# How to create a function to access elements of a nested object several levels deep with elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, processing

I am trying to reference a value inside several nested objects using values in an array

something like this

```
var object = {
  folder_1:{
    item: 8
  }
};
```

Then having it accessed by objects in an array in a button function

```
var button = function (x,y,z) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
};

button.prototype.run = function () {
  object[folder_1][item] = this.x;
  // expressed like this
  object[this.y] = this.x;
};

var b1 = new button(23,[folder_1,item],0);
```

Here is a snip of my current code and as you can see, it is very bulky and contains a large portion directed to my problem, however it only works up to 10 levels deep.

```
var vars = {
  library_1: {
    numbers: 7
  }
};

rectMode(CENTER);
textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);

var button = function (x,y,w,h,f,t,gt,ty,Arr) {
  //x coordinate
  this.x = x;
  //y coordinate
  this.y = y;
  //width
  this.w = w;
  //height
  this.h = h;
  //fill
  this.f = f;
  //text
  this.t = t;
  //scene to go to
  this.gt = gt;
  //type
  this.ty = ty;
  this.Arr = Arr;
  this.ArA = [];
};

button.prototype.draw = function () {
  fill(this.f);
  rect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h,5);

  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text(this.t,this.x,this.y);

  if(mouseX>this.x-this.w/2&&mouseX<this.x+this.w/2&&mouseY>this.y-this.h/2&&mouseY<this.y+this.h/2&&vars.mouse.clicked){
    //calibrate
    {
      vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]]-=1;
      vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]]+=1;
    }
    //sadly uncondensed system for changing variables in the system
    if(this.Arr===false){
      switch(this.ty.length){
        case 2:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 3:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 4:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[3]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 5:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[4]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 6:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[3]][this.ty[4]][this.ty[5]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 7:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[3]][this.ty[4]][this.ty[5]][this.ty[6]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 8:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[3]][this.ty[4]][this.ty[5]][this.ty[6]][this.ty[7]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 9:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[3]][this.ty[4]][this.ty[5]][this.ty[6]][this.ty[7]][this.ty[8]]=this.gt;
          break;
        case 10:
          vars[this.ty[0]][this.ty[1]][this.ty[2]][this.ty[3]][this.ty[4]][this.ty[5]][this.ty[6]][this.ty[7]][this.ty[8]][this.ty[9]]=this.gt;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
};

var f = new button(200,200,50,20,color(255, 0, 0),"=",0,['library_1','numbers'],false);

var draw = function(){
  if(vars.mouse.mouseIP === false && vars.mouse.mouseSense === true){
    vars.mouse.clicked = true;
    vars.mouse.mouseSense = false;
  }
  background(150,150,150);
  f.draw();
  //close button
  {
    fill(255,0,0);
    rect(width-25,10,50,20);
    fill(255,255,255);
    text("X",width-25,10);
    if (mouseX>width-50&&mouseY<20&&vars.mouse.clicked) {
      self.close();
    }
  }
  vars.mouse.clicked = false;
  vars.mouse.mouseIP = false;
  cursor(POINT);
};
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve]. Make sure to use proper indentation so your code is easier to read. Good luck.

Comment: Just give us the input & the wanted output & explain the conditions. Some of us are bored here

Comment: I want to make a function that allows for the object oriented change of values inside as many nested objects as is needed.  For example if I wanted to make a gui and use a library of objects as my variables instead of global variables I could create a user interface to change any value in the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explain better your question, i had to read about 10 times to understand what you want.

About the solution, instead using `switch` to iterate over the array, use one of the array builtin functions, like `map`.

Heres an example about what im talking. Put it on the dev-tools console to see the result.

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    value: 0,
    b: {
      value: 0,
      c: {
        value: 0,
        d: {
          value: 0,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function set(value, path) {
  var temp = obj;
  path && path.map(function (prop, index) {
    if ( temp.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
      if (path.length - 1 === index) 
        temp[prop] = value;
      else 
        temp = temp[prop];
    }
  });
}

set(1, ['a', 'value']);
set(2, ['a', 'b', 'value']);
set(3, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'value']);
set(4, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'value']);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And I will take your advice about questions too!